# SBT 0.10 - remove dependency on Scala 2.8.1

Tags: scala, sbt

My project uses Scala 2.9 so I've added

```
scalaVersion := "2.9.0-1"
```

to my `build.sbt` file, and run `gen-idea`. However IDEA still shows Scala 2.8.1 (in addition to 2.9) in External Libraries. Why, and how to remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application will be compiled with whatever Scala version or versions you choose. However, SBT is also a Scala application, and it was compiled with Scala 2.8.1, so *it* needs Scala 2.8.1's libraries to work. This will not have any impact on your application.

Comment: SBT will most likely switch to 2.9.1 as soon as it is released.